# Matplotlib draw proportional triangle

Tags: python, matplotlib, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, openai-api

My triangle drawing is appearing lopsided, how I make it proportional?

```
    points = np.array([[x, 10], [x/2, 10], [x+1/2, np.sqrt(5**2 - 2**2)]])
    pivot = plt.Polygon(points, closed = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the slanted side is 5 long, and the triangle has height 2, half the width will be `sqrt(5**2 + 2**2)`. Putting the left corner at position `x,y`, the right corner will be at the same `y` and the width added to `x`.  The central point will be at `x` plus half the width and `y+height`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('dark_background')
slanted_side = 5
height = 2
halfwidth = np.sqrt(slanted_side ** 2 - height ** 2)
y = 10

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
# x = self.target_location
x = 3
pivot_left = (x, y)
pivot_right = (x + 2 * halfwidth, y)
pivot_top = (x + halfwidth, y + height)
points = np.array([pivot_left, pivot_right, pivot_top])
pivot = plt.Polygon(points, closed=True)
axes.add_patch(pivot)
axes.set_xlim(0, 20)
axes.set_ylim(0, 20)
axes.set_aspect('equal') # equal distances in x and y directions
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: so X is actually a predetermined value, it is determined in the openAI gym env I made, called target_location. What I am really having trouble with is doing this with that target location.

Comment: what you gave me yields the triangle but in a random place, I need it to be in the target location because then it falls right below the rectangle and circle

Comment: Maybe you could print out `self.target_location` to know its value?

Comment: It is randomly generated each episode I believe, I added the code for self.target_location if that helps. I also reposted the question to make it more clear